# Fit 3D-Gaussian to tiff/png

Tags: image, gnuplot, data-fitting

I want to fit a 3D gaussian function to laser beam intensity profiles captured with a camera that can save images as tiff/png/jpg. I need the fit parameters and I want to plot the resulting fit later. I want to use gnuplot to do it.

What I do know:

- How to create a 3D gaussian function with the needed parameters:

```
f(x,y) = a/(sigmax*sigmay*2*pi) * exp( -((x-mux)**2/(2*sigmax**2) + ((y-muy)**2/(2*sigmay**2) ) + b
```

- How to fit using the parameters:

```
fit "data.dat" via a,b,sigmax,sigmay,mux,muy
```

- how to plot binary data:

```
plot "testpicture.png" binary filetype=png w image
```

What I do not know:

How to fit the function on the image file.
Do I need to convert the file first?

I much appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you want to fit data you have to get the data from the image first. Can you maybe post an example image?

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? Any feedback would be polite and appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please provide an example image for your case.
The following example might be a starting point for your task.

- the input file is a PNG (100x100 pixels) which has greyscale values from 0 to 255
- when reading the image data to the datablock `$Data` you get x,y-pixel values from 0 to 99. For proper scaling you have to enter your "real world" dimensions in micrometers or whatever.
- you need to guess reasonable initial values to make the fitting routing converging (some of the initial values must not be 0 for the fitting to start/converge).

Keep in mind that this should work if you have a circular/elliptic beam profile were the beam profile axes are aligned with the x- and y-axes. If the beam profile is elliptic and rotated in the x,y-plane you have to change your function `f(x,y)`.

**Input data:** (greyscale PNG image: `SO75832621.png`)

[image]

**Script:**

```
### 2D-gaussian fit of image data
reset session
set term wxt size 400,600    # or another terminal

FILE = "SO75832621.png"

# read file into datablock
set table $Data
    plot FILE binary filetype=png u 1:2:3 w rgbimage
unset table

# "real world" dimensions
xmin = -100
xmax =  100
ymin = -100
ymax =  100
stats $Data u 1:2 nooutput   # get min/max pixel values
myX(col) = (xmax-xmin)/(STATS_max_x - STATS_min_x)*column(col) + xmin
myY(col) = (ymax-ymin)/(STATS_max_y - STATS_min_y)*column(col) + ymin

f(x,y) = a/(sigmax*sigmay*2*pi) * exp( -((x-mux)**2/(2*sigmax**2) + ((y-muy)**2/(2*sigmay**2) ))) + b

# make some guesses for initial values
sigmax = abs(xmax-xmin)/4
sigmay = abs(ymax-ymin)/4
mux    = 0.1
muy    = 0.1
a      = 255*sigmax*sigmay*2*pi
b      = 0.1

set hidden3d
set xyplane relative 0
set palette grey
set key noautotitle
set samples    40
set isosamples 40
set xrange[xmin:xmax] noextend
set yrange[ymin:ymax] noextend

set fit brief nolog
fit f(x,y) $Data u (myX(1)):(myY(2)):3 via a,b,sigmax,sigmay,mux,muy

set multiplot layout 2,1

    set size ratio -1
    plot $Data u (myX(1)):(myY(2)):3 w image

    set view 60,30
    splot  f(x,y) w l lw 0.5
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 466005           +/- 65.47        (0.01405%)
b               = -0.0921087       +/- 0.003791     (4.115%)
sigmax          = 19.0993          +/- 0.002498     (0.01308%)
sigmay          = 15.2139          +/- 0.00199      (0.01308%)
mux             = -29.5972         +/- 0.002431     (0.008212%)
muy             = 32.7705          +/- 0.001936     (0.005908%)
```

[image]